# nth-child not responding on HTML using Handlebars

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In the code below, I am trying to use nth-child to have the 4th, 7th, 10th, etc. category be on a new line. I am unsure why the CSS code is not responding.

```css
#categories:nth-child(3n + 1) {clear: left;}
```

```html
{{#if categories}}
<div id="categories">
  {{#each categories}}
  <div class="category" id="category-unit" url="{{url}}">
    <div class="category-icon"></div>
    <div class="category-name">{{name}}</div>
    <span class="category-info"></span>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: I understand you want the 4th, 7th, 10th ect. selected. Do you want the first one selected as well? Or do you want it to start on the 4th element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to select the children of your `#categories`, not the div itself. Also, `:nth-child(3n + 1)` will also select the 1st element. If you want to select the 4th, 7th, 10th ect. without the first, do this:

**CSS**

```css
#categories > div:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(3n + 1) {
  background: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="categories">
  <div>The first paragraph.</div>
  <div>The second paragraph.</div>
  <div>The third paragraph.</div>
  <div>The fourth paragraph.</div>
  <div>The fifth paragraph.</div>
  <div>The sixth paragraph.</div>
  <div>The seventh paragraph.</div>
  <div>The eight paragraph.</div>
  <div>The ninth paragraph.</div>
  <div>The tenth paragraph.</div>
  <div>The eleventh paragraph.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah thanks, however I am unsure why it is not working.... I am using third-party software with HTML, CSS, and Javascript files available to me, but even when I added your code to the Javascript, it is not working.. perhaps a third party problem?

Comment: You're trying to apply the css to each `.category` class correct? Do you have a fiddle or a live link to your issue?

Comment: For some reason, after adding this it works: 
.category {
  float: left;
}
However, now it is floating at the left side of the screen, which I do not want.

Comment: It sounds like it was working all along, it's just whatever css rules you were applying didn't appear to be working. Again, if you can post your code in a fiddle or add a link to your project, that would make helping you a lot easier.

Comment: I am on my company's Zendesk Help Center template, which is why it may be difficult to copy a fiddle (not all the code is visible to me) or add a link (I am logged in to an admin account). Is there another way you can help?

Comment: Sadly I don't think so :/, try just adding a `border: 2px solid red;` to the selector to verify that it works. If so, then you may just need some different css within it to fix the layout of your divs. Which you can then post in a separate question with images so it will be more clear.

Comment: Ok, so I used this and it seems to be locating the correct div. Is there a way to make it simulate a <br/> without floating to the left, to make this div on a new line? (the original q)

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you're talking about. But it seems that the answer provided answers the question you asked. So if you want help regarding this other issue, it would be a lot easier if you created a new question with a specific description and some images so we know what you're looking at :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114884/discussion-between-keyan-r-and-hunter-turner).

Comment: If the OP is looking to only apply `clear: left;` to the 4th, 7th, 10th, etc. elements, it won't matter if the `:nth-child( 3n + 1 )` selector also clears the 1st child element as there isn't anything to clear and won't adversely affect the layout. IMHO I wouldn't worry about a solution to avoid the 1st element until visual style differences come into play. See my answer and [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vhwsyre/) below.

Answer (score 2):

nth-child should target the classes/elements you want to filter. You want the `.category` elements clear every X items so you should target them and not `#categories`.

```css
#categories .category:nth-child(3n + 1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vhwsyre/).